# Magento 1.9 open header mini cart when product is added to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, mini-cart

I want to open the header cart when a product is added to the cart on my Magento 1.9.4.1 store, by adding the class `display:block;` to my header cart div after the page is re-loaded.

I use the default cart method, that the page refresh and the product is added to the cart.

My header cart got the div `<div class="cart-wrapper" id="mini-header-cart">`

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

I am almost there using the success message element, but I do not want to check the length of the success message, but if the success message contains a add to cart phrase. Any ideas how to change my code?

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    if ($('.messages .success-msg').length){
                     var screen_width = $(window).width();
                    if (screen_width > 780) {$('.cart-container .cart-wrapper').css('display','block');}
                    }
                </script>
```